# How to soften edges of a Rectangle SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently running into a problem of "harsh" edges when I try to create a rounded rectangle using a gradient.[image]

In this gradient you can see around the corners it gets especially dark, and I'm not sure how to fix this.

I'm guessing it's stemming from using an extension to create the gradient so that I can use it as the foreground color instead of the background, but I'm not sure what I would use instead to fix this problem.

```
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .gradientForeground(colors: [Color("MainColor1"), Color("MainColor2")])
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.9, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                .padding(.leading, geometry.size.width * 0.05)
        
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    public func gradientForeground(colors: [Color]) -> some View {
        self.overlay(LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: colors),
                                    startPoint: .topLeading,
                                    endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
            .mask(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working on **Shape** because you used `RoundedRectangle`, the right and correct way of coloring is `fill`, your issue is not connected to **View** to make an **extension** but it is about **Shape**.

---

[image]

---

```
extension Shape  {

    public func gradientForeground(colors: [Color]) -> some View {
        self.fill(LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: colors), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))

    }
}
```

---

***Use case:***

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {

        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50)
            .gradientForeground(colors: [Color.red, Color.yellow])
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: Alignment.center)
  
    }
}
```